# as_json not calling as_json on associations rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `User` which `has_one :bank`
I have overwritten `as_json` for both models and in the `User` model, I do this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]

  def as_json(options = {})
    super({include[:bank]}.merge(options))
  end
end
```

the problem is that it doesn't call the overwritten as_json in the Bank class.

Any idea how to make this work ?

Thanks

Comment: `{include[:bank]}` looks like an invalid `Hash`

Answer (score 0):

You should not override `to_json` or `as_json`. Instead, override [`serializable_hash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html#method-i-serializable_hash) which both of these methods use.

Answer (score -1):

You can include an association in the result of [`as_json`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) as follows:

```
User.last.as_json(include: :bank)
```

To do it globally, add this to `User` model:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super(options.merge(include: :bank))
end
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know the reason for downvote. I would be glad to improve my answer or failing to do that, delete it.